# Added child items are added to parent but after ajax request removed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I made a website that give the artist that gives the related artists from an artist. If I do the request to get the related artist from Michael Jackson *(in my example)* to a Spotify API the data returns and the I fill the tree.

I've debugged my code whit Google Chrome and I see that the artists are added to the section after the for loop.

[image]

But the problem is now, when I stop whit debugging (<kbd>F8</kbd>), everything is cleared!

[image]

**Edit:** I've also tried with other artists and some work, others not. Once tried an artist, the code don't works anymore...

What's the problem? Here you have my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/337xztyt/).

```
function init() {
    $('body').on("click", ".artist-node", function() {
        var id = $(this).find("input").val();
        var rijnr = $(this).data("rij");

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/" + id + "/related-artists",
            success: function(data) {
                var aantal = data.artists.length;

                var rij = $('<div class="boom-rij" data-rij="2"></div>');
                $(".draw-area").append(rij);

                for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
                    vulNodesAan(data.artists[i], 2, rij);   
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function vulNodesAan(data, rijnr, rij) {

    var imgData = geefImage(data.images);
    $(rij).append('<div class="artist-node"><input type="hidden" value="' + data.id + '"/><div class="artist-foto-container"><img src="' + imgData.url + '" alt="" /></div><p>' + data.name + '</p></div>');
}
```

Sorry but some code is written in Dutch.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify where the problem occurs? If i use the fiddle, search for michael and click on the bubble it is loaded

Comment: @BDays: can you give me your link?

Comment: @BDays: that's wired I've sometime it will works and other moments not. Can you try an other artist?

Comment: Will try, and yea I just got the same problem when i retried the link to send you

Comment: Tried with a few other artists and it works, no modification to the code.

Comment: So playing with the fiddle revealed some things that may help. You can have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/337xztyt/1/ so you can follow. Basically the appending of the new data div doesn't always work yet the console logs the messages before and after. Hopefully this helps you get closer to your answer. (You will also see where I used appendChild and innerHTML. neither worked)